# WebAPI in memory testing - getting error serialize IQueryable

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have WebAPI implementation with method like this:

```
 public IEnumerable<Device> GetAllDevices()
 public Device GetDeviceById(int id)
```

Looks ok, it works when running in IIS or selfhosted. Returns JSON objects correctly.

However first method fails in my unit test where I attempt to use inmemory server.

```
 System.InvalidOperationException : Cannot create and populate list type System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Test.Device].
```

This goes down to  Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization assembly. An example of the test follow:

```
        [Test]
    public void GET_AskingForListOfDevices_GettingOk200WithListOfDevicesInJSON()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient(InMemoryServer);
        HttpRequestMessage request = CreateRequest("api/devices", "application/json", HttpMethod.Get);

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result)
        {
            Assert.That(response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(HttpStatusCode.OK));
            Assert.NotNull(response.Content);
            Assert.AreEqual("application/json", response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType);

            // next line throws exc
            var content = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IQueryable<Device>>().Result;

            Assert.AreEqual(3, content.Count());
        }

        request.Dispose();
    }
```

Any idea where to look?

UPDATE
The example below throws that error, however I found the solution to avoid it. Just by using IList<> instead of IQueryable<>. Still It does not answer me the question why it's working in Fiddler. Does it use the same trick?

Comment: Can u show the implementation of those action method and your tests.

Answer (score 2):

I am running into same situation. IQueryable throws exception but if you use IEnumerable then it works.